# To pass a variable to block in Ruby implicitely

Tags: ruby

I'd like to rewrite that snippet:

```
Chips.fix_game(324565) do |game_id|
  player1.chips.gain(game_id, 200) # chips qty
  player2.chips.lose(game_id, 200)
end
```

such way:

```
Chips.fix_game(324565) do
  player1.chips.gain(200)
  player2.chips.lose(200)
end
```

somehow passing `game_id` to `player1.chips` API entry point.

The second snippet is more laconic and there is no space to change `game_id` inside the block.

How would you implicitely pass `game_id` value from `Chips.fix_game` method to `player1.chips` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Chips` could provide a `current_game_id` that is set using `fix_game`, e.g.:

```
class Chips
  @@current_game_id = nil

  def self.current_game_id
    @@current_game_id
  end

  def self.fix_game(game_id)
    previous_game_id = current_game_id
    @@current_game_id = game_id
    yield
  ensure
    @@current_game_id = previous_game_id
  end
end

class Player
  def gain(amount)
    puts "gaining #{amount} chips in game #{Chips.current_game_id}"
  end
end

player = Player.new

Chips.fix_game(1) do
  player.gain(100)
end
#=> "gaining 100 chips in game 1"

Chips.fix_game(2) do
  player.gain(200)
end
#=> "gaining 200 chips in game 2"
```

Restoring the previous game id after `yield` allows to nest blocks:

```
Chips.current_game_id     #=> nil
Chips.fix_game(1) do
  Chips.current_game_id   #=> 1
  Chips.fix_game(2) do
    Chips.current_game_id #=> 2
  end
  Chips.current_game_id   #=> 1
end
Chips.current_game_id     #=> nil
```

Although this looks convenient, global state can lead to difficult-to-debug problems. Take care.

Comment: Ok, I see you. I need no nesting Chips.fix_game, though. What about multithreading?