# Is it possible to get rid of class variable?

Tags: ruby

I started with [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035272/to-pass-a-variable-to-block-in-ruby-implicitely)

My goal is to try an unusual, but interesting way of calling a block. I came to that code:

```
class Chips
  def self.configure player_class, player_id_method, player_api_method
    player_class.send :define_method, player_api_method do
      Chips::Player.new(self.send player_id_method)
    end
  end

  def self.fix_game game_id
    @@game_results = {game_id: game_id, players: []}
    yield
    puts @@game_results.inspect
  end

  class Player
    def initialize player_id
      @player_id= player_id
    end

    def gain chips
      Chips.send :fix_player, @player_id, chips.abs
    end

    def lose chips
      Chips.send :fix_player, @player_id, -chips.abs
    end
  end

  def self.fix_player player_id, chips
    @@game_results[:players]<< {player_id: player_id, chips: chips}
  end

  private_class_method :fix_player
end

class User
  attr_reader :email
  def initialize email
    @email = email
  end
end

Chips.configure User, :email, :chips
p1= User.new 'david@gmail.com'
p2= User.new 'simon@gmail.com'

# p1.chips and p2.chips should have access to the value 
# currently accessible by @@game_results reference
Chips.fix_game 3333 do
  p1.chips.gain 300
  p2.chips.lose 300
end
```

... which outputs `{:game_id=>3333, :players=>[{:player_id=>"david@gmail.com", :chips=>300}, {:player_id=>"simon@gmail.com", :chips=>-300}]}`

I would like to avoid class variable using.

**ps**

Question creation form hadn't allow me to submit this question until I added more words, which are in fact a pray to The Mighty Doorkeeper. I've brought you more bytes, TMD. I obey.

Comment: Why not simply have a class with state? `Chips.new`... etc.?

Comment: Why not, btw? Can you post a working snippet?

Comment: No. Your design is very convoluted, I suggest you should rework your design from the bottom up, and try again. For such a simple use case, there is no need to use metaprogramming. If you find yourself using `send` or `define_method` - you are probably on the wrong track. Keep it simple

Comment: I totally agree with you, I'm just playing words )